# All my desktop icons have disappeared in gnome shell ubuntu 12.10 after 6 March update

Tags: gnome, updates, icons

I have lost all Desktop icons after updating on 6 March. I updated from Canonical's archive directly as I thought they would test software before they release it. When I run gnome tweak tool it says there are no extensions installed. They were all there on 5 March but not on 6 March after update.

I tried to download them again but they are greyed out and will not install.

How can I get my icons back in gnome shell?

Thanks.

The only desktop that works is gnome classic (no effects) all the others are blank with a mouse pointer that moves but does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: The problem was an incompatibility between gnome shell and nvidia's driver version 310. I uninstalled the driver and installed nvidia-current from the ubuntu archive. All the icons are back and I can install new extensions again.
Rob Key